# What could cause my BMW 340i to show both engine codes PO171 and PO172?

Tags: fuel-injection, fuel-tank

I have a 2016 BMW 340i which recently turned on the check engine light.

FIXD shows me this:

[image]

I’ve also had two incidents where the car has struggled to start after filling up the tank. The engine would  would stall the first time I try to turn it on. The next time I gently pressed the gas right after turning it on, after which I switched to D and it worked fine. We always get the highest octane fuel.

My understanding is that a too rich fuel mix could have multiple causes. But what could have caused the fuel mix to be both too rich and too lean?

I’m taking this car to a mechanic, but would like to have some idea of what’s happening before I do.

Comment: Two things. First, clear the codes and see what comes back. Second, the P0172 is a detected issue. P0171 is a "possible" issue, meaning, the code reader is taking a guess. P0172, being an actual issue, is what you need to chase.

Comment: That no start issue?  I’m thinking fuel pressure. If you turn key to on  (listen for fuel pump for two seconds) then start, does it always start reliably?